# Open source BPMN language

Tags: open-source, workflow

We are planning to use jBPM for workflow management. The amount of resource for different scenarios ( calling REST Services, Drools integration) is very less. If there is a better alternative do suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Camunda BPM is a better solution.

Comment: Your answer has been flag as low quality and might be removed; please have a look at [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/23377) for some tips on how to improve it.